# QNetworkReply readyRead signal and read&readAll function crashes in multi-threaded environment

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I tried to start the HTTP protocol in a thread to download a file, but I found that QNetworkReply calling the read or readAll method in a multithreaded environment would cause the program to crash. It can only write a few tens of MB of file each time, and then it crashes for no reason.

work.h

```
#ifndef WORK_H
#define WORK_H
#include <QFile>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QEventLoop>

class Work:public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Work(QString _fileName,QUrl _url,qint64 _offset, qint64 _end):fileName(_fileName),url(_url),
        offset(_offset),end(_end){ }

protected:
    void run () override;

private:
    QString fileName;
    QUrl url;
    qint64 offset;
    qint64 end;

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    QFile *file;
    QByteArray buf;
    QTime lastTime;
    qint64 lastByte=0;
};

#endif // WORK_H
```

work.cpp

```
#include "work.h"

#define KB 1024
#define MB KB*1024

void Work::run()
{
    Qt::HANDLE curId=QThread::currentThread();

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

    file=new QFile(fileName);
    if(!file->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
        return;
    }

    file->seek(offset);

    //reply->setReadBufferSize(1024*2); //**Only set the access data to be less than 2Kb to avoid crashing; If the access data size is not set or set to greater than 2kb, it will also crash**
    connect(reply,&QNetworkReply::readyRead,this,[&](){
        while(reply->bytesAvailable()>0){
            buf = reply->readAll();
            //buf=reply->read(reply->bytesAvailable());   These two lines of code will crash if calling read() or readAll() function to read the buffer, On the contrary, once I try to annotate tow lines, it won't crash**
            file->write(buf);
        }
    });

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, [&](qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal) {
        if (bytesTotal > 0) {
            int percentage = static_cast<int>((bytesReceived * 100) / bytesTotal);
           qDebug() << "Downloaded" << percentage << "%";
        }
    });

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]() {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            qDebug() << "Download completed successfully!";
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Download failed:" << reply->errorString();
        }
        file->close();
        reply->deleteLater();
        manager->deleteLater();
        quit();
    });

    exec();
}
```

This is the debugging result：

[image]

Comment: First - why do you need a thread for this? Second - your readyRead() slot is executed in the main thread as your QThread object lives in the main thread. Please follow the examples in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#details)...

Comment: Please do not add text based information as an image, it limits the ease of finding this post to future readers. Add the debugging results as text into your question to maximize its availability. For more details, please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You attached a debugger to this and got it to crash. Very good. Now show us the actual stack trace and variables window. That will very probably highlight the "no reason" why it crashes. My money is on the memory belonging to `Work` being freed and scribbled over somehow.

Comment: Also, how do you _use_ Work from outside?

Comment: @chehrlic Yes, I did it, thank you very much! I tried defining a QThread object in the main thread, calling the moveToThread() method of the work object, and triggering a signal for the thread to start download the file. During this period, my main window did not show any unresponsive state, and the file download was completed. But I still haven't figured out why the original code kept crashing.

Comment: @Shu橡树Xiang as Botje noted, you never showed how `Work` is used from outside. We cannot answer you if you don't provide a valid [mre]. Besides, creating a QThread to move your `Work` object doesn't make a lot of sense, since it already is a QThread.